# Assigning colours to a variable in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know there are similar questions elsewhere on here but I am really struggling to understand the answers. I have a CSV file with 5 columns (town name, latitude, longitude, wind speed, wind direction), I can plot the arrows on a map with the right orientation on them, I just want to be able to colour the arrows depending on the number in the wind speed column.

```
with open('output.csv') as latloncsv:
    towns_csv = csv.reader(latloncsv, dialect='excel')
    for rows in towns_csv:
        x = float(rows[2]) # x co-ordinates
        y = float(rows[1]) # y co-ordinates
        u = float(rows[3]) # wind speed
        v = float(rows[4]) # wind direction
        for color in u:
            if color <= 2:
                letter = ('g')
            elif color <=4:
                letter = ('y')
            elif color <=6:
                letter = ('b')
            elif color <=8:
                letter = ('p')
            else:
                letter = ('r')
            plt.plot(x, y, marker=(3, 0, v), markersize='10', color= ('color'))
    UKMap.UKMap.__init__('self') 
    plt.show()
```

I can make it any single colour but I just want to know how to vary the code so that I can make it vary in colour.

```
 color= ('color'))
```

Sorry if this badly writtin, I'm still learning. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
with open('output.csv') as latloncsv:
    towns_csv = csv.reader(latloncsv, dialect='excel')
    for rows in towns_csv:
        x = float(rows[2]) # x co-ordinates
        y = float(rows[1]) # y co-ordinates
        u = float(rows[3]) # wind speed
        v = float(rows[4]) # wind direction
        if u <= 2:
            color = 'g'
        elif u <=4:
            color = 'y'
        elif u <=6:
            color = 'b'
        elif u <=8:
            color = 'p'
        else:
            color = 'r'
            plt.plot(x, y, marker=(3, 0, v), markersize='10', color=color)
    UKMap.UKMap.__init__('self') 
    plt.show()
```

...i'm not entirely sure about your data (and could therefore not test) but that should work.

also note: the brackets aroud string (or any identifier) as in `('b')` have absolutely no effect; this is the same as `'b'`

and the line `UKMap.UKMap.__init__('self')` looks very suspect! shouldn't that be something like `uk_map = UKMap.UKMap()` (and maybe some arguments; but the string `'self'` is very strange!)? `self` (not as string) is usually just used inside a class definition and not used outside a class.